Distance from the surface as an input node for volumetric materials on open meshes: distance to closest point of the mesh volumetric function
Is there any way to create a material that has a volumetric component and is defined using the closest distance to the surface?
I am particularly interested in open meshes and not just closed volumes. There is a very similar question that addresses this, but the solution only works on the inner side of closed volumes. I an interested in something that work on both sides (inner and outer from the normal) and doesn't needs the volume to be closed, for example a plane with curves like the image:

Things that I've already tried:

Using geometry nodes to calculate the proximity to the faces of the object. I wasn't able to make it work like this.
Using texture coordinates node I can only compute the distance to the center of the object but not to the mesh itself.
Tried to adapt the script from this answer, but I can't make it work with open surfaces. In this case I enclosed my mesh under a big cube and tried to compute all the points inside the cube that are at a distance < d, but I wasn't able to make this work.

All the blender options that I could find work on surfaces but not with volumes. Any idea how to address this?
One trivial option here is the solidify modifier, but since I have complex open surfaces with faces intersecting sometimes the solidify modifier does not work. That's why I want to be able to have a function distance to closest point of the mesh that don't need normals to work and just uses location of the mesh.
At the end of the day, I want to be able to control a volumetric node with this info. Basically constrain the volumetric shader (for example emission) to this region.
